# Spring MVC Clicked DIV with values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a for loop on a JSP page to display a div containing a div which has a few data. I want the inner div to be clicked and the values to be passed to the controller.

```
<for>
<div>
<div>
<span>data</span>
</div>
</div>
</for>
```

How can i implement this functionality to make the entire div clickable and capture the data thats there in the DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
$("div").click(function(){ 
  alert($(this).find('span').html());
});
```

that code will be show value of span in div element.
don't forget you must use jquery to access this function,

if you want send to controller you can using $.ajax() request and response to server

```
$("div").click(function(){ 
      var value = $(this).find('span').html();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/yourController",//just example
        data: "data=" +  value,
        success:function(data,msg){
           alert(msg);
        }
      });
    });
```

and in server you get params `data`